# Webview control consumes too much memory in WP 8.1 Runtime

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 Store app (C#/XAML) and I use a Webview control on one of the app pages. Everything was OK until my app started to close with no exceptions. I suspected memory issues and was actually right. I've made some profiling and became certain the problem was with the Webview control. When I navigate to some web page, the (unmanaged) memory consumption grows rapidly, and in some further navigations it exceeds the memory limits (180 MB for low-memory devices) and the app terminates. Manual garbage collector calls do not help even when the page that hosts Webview control is closed. I am stuck now and have no idea how I can deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually invoke `GC.Dispose` after setting to null the parent of WebView parent.Content or invoke `parent.Children.Clear()` depending on the context.

The WebView contains internal cache which you can't dispose from your code.
The solution [is here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/892a56d2-973b-4f35-8101-8a630e9c77fd/webview-control-consumes-too-much-memory-in-wp-81-runtime?forum=wpdevelop).